# HTTP POST ValueError: Unterminated string, for base 64 encoded string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, http-post

I am trying to post the following string as content to my python server:

```
id&p=7&x=11814&y=25712&yr=0&m=7&d=26&h=13&s=75
```

However I got the unterminated string error on the server side. Then I use methodd windows.btoa() to encode the message and try to send again and still get the save error. The encoded message:

```
aWQmcD03Jng9MTE4MTQmeT0yNTcxMiZ5cj0wJm09NyZkPTI2Jmg9MTMmcz03NQ==
```

My server side code (python):

```
   def do_POST(self):

    """Respond to a POST request."""

    ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers.getheader('content-type'))
    if ctype == 'multipart/form-data':
        postvars = cgi.parse_multipart(self.rfile, pdict)
    elif ctype == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
        length = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length'))
        postvars = cgi.parse_qs(self.rfile.read(length), keep_blank_values=1)
    else:
        postvars = {}

    print '!!!postvars: ', postvars.keys()[0]
```

Please help if I am doing anything wrong here or if there's a better way for doing this... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show your Javascript code that does the posting. I think you're forgetting to call `encodeURIComponent`. This is necessary because `=` is special in URI parameters.

Comment: Thank you, I am really new to this. Should have used encodeURIComponent instead of base64 encoding.